# Localhost not working on XAMPP 1.7.7 for Windows 7

Tags: xampp

My xampp installation 1.7.7 does not seem to work. http://localhost returns search results on localhost

XAMPP instaled in C:\xampp

Xampp Control panel shows both mysql & apache service running fine.

Changed Skype internet connection settings (Tools-Options-Advanced-Connection panel and deselected the "Use 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections")

I'am on windows 7.

Turned IIS off ( Control Panel-­System and Security-Administrative Tools-Internet Information Services Manager-Manage Server- Stop)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

As I saw this is common "problem" for Windows 7 and VIsta - in some cases these systems doesn't know 'localhost'. 
Try use http://127.0.0.1 or add one line to file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
This line is:

```
127.0.0.1             localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a different problem. The following fixed it for me. Thought I'd share

Open:
xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

And check the line:
DocumentRoot path/to/home/dir

For me this was pointing to default location so I had to change it to my custom location.

Restart Apache and you're done