# My localhost turns localhost.com

Tags: php, joomla, xampp, jomsocial

I am working on a [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) local server.

My localhost turns localhost.com. When I run my localhost in browser for ex (localhost/projects/test) the url turns www.localhost.com/projects/test.

Comment: That sounds like something your browser (Firefox does this) is doing. Instead of typing `localhost`, use `http://localhost`.  Or via IP `http://127.0.0.1`

Comment: Are you using .htaccess?

Comment: This has nothing to do with php and xampp; it's simply your browser.

Comment: Try the solution listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947373/localhost-not-working-on-xampp-1-7-7-for-windows-7?rq=1 (edit your hosts file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working on a computer running the Mac Mountain Lion OS (10.8), Apple made changes in this version of the OS that have caused problems for some, and you'll need to change some of your computer's settings to get localhost working properly. [This page](http://www.codepotato.co.uk/2012/07/25/enabling-localhost-on-os-x-mountain-lion/) provides a good walkthrough on how to make localhost work again.

Answer (score 0):

Try `http://localhost/...` instead of just plain `localhost/...`.

Comment: I have tried both these steps.Its not turning for all the pages. But for certain pages regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Try `http://localhost/` sometimes webbrowser tries to be smarter then a user.